# How old is Alucard?

Tags: hellsing

We know that Dracula was defeated in the past (some 100 years before the series begun). That's when his name was changed to Alucard.

However, it's obvious that he lived before that. How long did he live? Do we have an estimated timeline of events?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Hellsing Wikia](http://hellsing.wikia.com/wiki/Alucard#History) he was born in 1431. That makes him 582 years old today. But it also states that he was 568 years old in 1999, and 599 after a time skip.

> [...]Born in 1431, [...] He is arguably the first vampire that ever existed.
>
> 568 (1999),599 (time skip)

Comment: Do we know where this information is taken from?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I think it came from the "original Dracula" In Wikipedia stays: "Vlad III, Prince of Wallachia (1431–1476), [...], also known by his patronymic name: Dracula." Since Alucard is/was Dracula the Information seems to be from here.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [hellsing-wiki](http://hellsing.wikia.com/wiki/Alucard):

> 568 (1999), 599 (time skip)

Answer (score 0):

Alucard is the name his master gave him because it is Dracula backward, but later in the anime, Alucard states his name was Vlad Tepes to his master.

If you look into Alucard's backstory and check out his age, it says he was born in 1431 and his age now would be 582 years old, and 568 years in 1999, and 599 in a time skip. If you look further and check out the name Vlad Tepes and read his backstory, you will get that he is known to clear forests of men by impaling them, which caused him to get the name Vlad the Impaler by the Ottoman that so came across the impaled men.

But that's not the point. The point is that if you check out the year he was born in which was in 1431 same as Alucard, his age now would be 588 years as of today, and Alucard's age is 582 as of today (very close to each other), but ironically they have nothing in common at all. They only have very little things that correspond with each other.

So, theoretically, Alucard's name is just a name and has nothing to do with the actual person, except that Vlad died and is (just a tale) haunting his victims and torturing them as an undead creature; just like Alucard, because he is undead too.

Answer (score -1):

Alucard is 598 years old as a demon vampire. But when he was human, it was to be said that he was 45 years old, despite his 30-year-old appearance.